# Flowmap OGL effect on a PNG

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, ogl

According to this example : https://github.com/oframe/ogl/blob/master/examples/mouse-flowmap.html I should be able to recreate the flowmap effect but nothing is happening.

The thing is that this example is for a single image with no scrolling or layout constraint. I have been trying to implement it into my project (I have a PNG working as a hero on my landing page with a responsive width and height and I want to turn it into a texture in a canvas with the same width and height).

Here is my code :

```
import { Renderer, Program, Texture, Mesh, Vec2, Flowmap, Triangle } from '../node_modules/ogl/src/index.js';

const bounds = document.querySelector('.c-titreMael img').getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(bounds);

            const vertex = /* glsl */ `
                attribute vec2 uv;
                attribute vec2 position;

                varying vec2 vUv;

                void main() {
                    vUv = uv;
                    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
                }
            `;

            const fragment = /* glsl */ `
                precision highp float;

                uniform sampler2D tWater;
                uniform sampler2D tFlow;
                uniform float uTime;

                varying vec2 vUv;

                void main() {

                    // R and G values are velocity in the x and y direction
                    // B value is the velocity length
                    vec3 flow = texture2D(tFlow, vUv).rgb;

                    // Use flow to adjust the uv lookup of a texture
                    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / 600.0;
                    uv += flow.xy * 0.05;
                    vec3 tex = texture2D(tWater, uv).rgb;

                    // Oscillate between raw values and the affected texture above
                    //tex = mix(tex, flow * 0.5 + 0.5, smoothstep( -0.3, 0.7, sin(uTime)));

                    gl_FragColor.rgb = tex;
                    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
                    
                }
            `;


                const renderer = new Renderer({ dpr: 2 });
                const gl = renderer.gl;
                const monCanvas = document.querySelector('.c-titreMael')
                monCanvas.classList.add('.parallelisme');
                monCanvas.appendChild(gl.canvas);

                // Variable inputs to control flowmap
                let aspect = 1;
                const mouse = new Vec2(-1);
                const velocity = new Vec2();

                function resize() {
                    renderer.setSize(bounds.width, bounds.height);
                    aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                }
                window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
                resize();

                const flowmap = new Flowmap(gl);
                

                // Triangle that includes -1 to 1 range for 'position', and 0 to 1 range for 'uv'.
                const geometry = new Triangle(gl);

                const texture = new Texture(gl, { wrapS: gl.REPEAT, wrapT: gl.REPEAT });
                const img = new Image();
                img.onload = () => {
                    texture.image = img,
                    texture.needsUpdate = true;
                };
                img.src = './assets/images/TitreMael.png';

                const program = new Program(gl, {
                    vertex,
                    fragment,
                    uniforms: {
                        uTime: { value: 0 },
                        tWater: { value: texture },

                        // Note that the uniform is applied without using an object and value property
                        // This is because the class alternates this texture between two render targets
                        // and updates the value property after each render.
                        tFlow: flowmap.uniform,
                    },
                });

                const mesh = new Mesh(gl, { geometry, program });

                // Create handlers to get mouse position and velocity
                const isTouchCapable = 'ontouchstart' in window;
                if (isTouchCapable) {
                    window.addEventListener('touchstart', updateMouse, false);
                    window.addEventListener('touchmove', updateMouse, false);
                } else {
                    window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateMouse, false);
                }

                let lastTime;
                const lastMouse = new Vec2();
                function updateMouse(e) {
                    if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches.length) {
                        e.x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
                        e.y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
                    }
                    if (e.x === undefined) {
                        e.x = e.pageX;
                        e.y = e.pageY;
                    }

                    // Get mouse value in 0 to 1 range, with y flipped
                    mouse.set(e.x / gl.renderer.width, 1.0 - e.y / gl.renderer.height);

                    // Calculate velocity
                    if (!lastTime) {
                        // First frame
                        lastTime = performance.now();
                        lastMouse.set(e.x, e.y);
                    }

                    const deltaX = e.x - lastMouse.x;
                    const deltaY = e.y - lastMouse.y;

                    lastMouse.set(e.x, e.y);

                    let time = performance.now();

                    // Avoid dividing by 0
                    let delta = Math.max(14, time - lastTime);
                    lastTime = time;

                    velocity.x = deltaX / delta;
                    velocity.y = deltaY / delta;

                    // Flag update to prevent hanging velocity values when not moving
                    velocity.needsUpdate = true;
                }

                requestAnimationFrame(update);
                function update(t) {
                    requestAnimationFrame(update);

                    // Reset velocity when mouse not moving
                    if (!velocity.needsUpdate) {
                        mouse.set(-1);
                        velocity.set(0);
                    }
                    velocity.needsUpdate = false;

                    // Update flowmap inputs
                    flowmap.aspect = aspect;
                    flowmap.mouse.copy(mouse);

                    // Ease velocity input, slower when fading out
                    flowmap.velocity.lerp(velocity, velocity.len() ? 0.5 : 0.1);

                    flowmap.update();

                    program.uniforms.uTime.value = t * 0.001;

                    renderer.render({ scene: mesh });
                }
```

Here is the vue template related :

```
<template>
    <div class="c-titreMael">
        <img class="titreMael" src="../assets/images/TitreMael.png" alt="Titre Mael"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have no errors, just the animation of this flow :

```
// Oscillate between raw values and the affected texture above
//tex = mix(tex, flow * 0.5 + 0.5, smoothstep( -0.3, 0.7, sin(uTime)));
```

And when I remove it the canvas becomes fully black, no picture or anything.

I tried to put a transparent : true in the texture... nothing. Alpha: true in the renderer, nothing as well. I guess the problem must be in the fragment / vertex...